# Permission denied @ dir_initialize Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, file-permissions, ubuntu-20.04

in `initialize': Permission denied @ dir_initialize - /home/HirushaFernando/picq-web/db/store/397/397452a5-c254-4025-90cc-6884ae4eab04/202207_302756_302756_0 (Errno::EACCES)

Didn't work these commands
`sudo chown -R User:User db/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you change the mode too: `chmod -R u+rwX db`